# How to close date picker modal when date is selected in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datepicker, expo

I am using `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` for the date picker. Everything is working fine but what I face is about to close the date picker modal. Actually, I want to close a modal when the user selects a date. I really tried hard but didn't a solution to resolve my problem. Could someone please help me with how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

**Code**

```
onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    if (event.type) {
      switch (event.type) {
        // Handle dismissing the datepicker modal on Android
        case "dismissed":
          setShow(false);
          return;
        // Handle setting the currently selected value on Android
        case "set":
          setShow(false);
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
    }
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    this.fetchAllOrders(currentDate);
    this.setState({
      show: Platform.OS === "ios",
      date: currentDate,
    });
  };


<DateTimePicker
value={date}
minimumDate={Date.parse(new Date())}
display="default"
mode={mode}
onChange={this.onChange}
style={{ width: "90%" }}
/>
```

Comment: it seems is not supported by design https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/483 https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/297

Comment: This happens on android or ios?